# How to integrate external shopping cart into a Facebook Application

Tags: facebook

I have an existing shopping cart that is hosted on a 3rd party server. Is it possible to use an iframe or some other method to display the shopping cart from within Facebook?

If the answer is yes, could you please outline the required steps?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Have your web application reside within a Facebook tab/context.  Read up on [canvas applications](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/) and [iframe tabs](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462/).

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is YES : But you will need some work.

First you need to create a facebook application : http://facebook.com/developers

Then you will have to specify your canvas Page and Canvas URL and maybe your tab URL.

Facebook will then use the canvas URL in a iframe for your app.

So for example if you defined your canvas page as : `http://apps.facebook.com/my_super_shopping_cart`

And your canvas URL as : `http://www.my_super_shopping_cart.com/canvas/`

And your tab URL as : `http://www.my_super_shopping_cart.com/tab/`

Then if you visit your facebook app at adress : `http://apps.facebook.com/my_super_shopping_cart`

It will basically display a facebook page with a 760 pixels wide iframe in the middle with iframe source being `http://www.my_super_shopping_cart.com/canvas/`

And if someone adds your application to it's facebook page as a tab. Then when a user visits the tab in question, it will display a 520 px wide iframe inside the tab , and the iframe will points to `http://www.my_super_shopping_cart.com/tab/`

Now if you want to get some info from the user, you will have to authenticate the user to facebook, for more details on all this you should check : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/